# rowsPerPageTemplate Dropdown dissapears after selection change and clicking away

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have Datatables(PrimeFaces 8.0.1) on multiple pages, only one of them had rows and rowsPerPageTemplate attributes, now i need to modify all other DataTables in the same way. All DataTables (dataTableA,dataTableB,..) are almost identical and have own @SessionScoped Beans(ControllerA, ControllerB,..). At first all DataTables seem to be OK, but if i change the  rows per page selection of a dataTableX and click away to another page/dataTable and then i turn back to dataTableX, rows per page dropdown isn't there anymore (for the rest of the session). Can anyone help please? Thank you.

listViewA.xhtml

```
        <h:form id="listAUserForm">
          <p:dataTable id="dataTableA"
                     value="#{controllerA.listA}" 
                     reflow="true"
                     paginator="true"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} &nbsp;&nbsp; #{msg.rows_per_page}: {RowsPerPageDropdown}" 
                     currentPageReportTemplate="#{prop.current_page_report_template}"
                     paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                     var="entryA" 
                     rows="#{controllerA.rowsPerPage}" 
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,{ShowAll|'All'}"
                     rowKey="#{entryA}" 
                     selection="#{controllerA.entriesSelected}">
            <p:ajax event="rowSelectCheckbox" listener="#{controllerA.onRowSelect}" update=":toolbarA" />
            <p:ajax event="rowUnselectCheckbox" listener="#{controllerA.onRowUnselect}" update=":toolbarA" />
            <p:ajax event="toggleSelect"  process="@this" partialSubmit="true" update=":toolbarA"/>
            <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:16px;text-align:center"/>
....
....
</h:form>
```

ControllerA.java

```
@ManagedBean(name = "ControllerA")
@SessionScoped
public class ControllerA extends BaseController
{
     private int rowsPerPage = 10;
     private List<EntryA> entries= null;


    public int getRowsPerPage()
    {
        return rowsPerPage;
    }

    public void setRowsPerPage(int rowsPerPage)
    {
        this.rowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
    }
    public List<EntryA> getListA()
    {
        if (entries== null)
        {
            entries= new ArrayList<>();
            List<EntryA> tmpListA;
            try
            {
                tmpListA= getSecurityServiceLocator().getBeanA().getAllEntries();
            }
            catch (SecurityException ex)
            {
                LOGGER.error("Error retrieving listA", ex);
                return Collections.emptyList();
            }

            if (!isFilterExist())
            {
                entries.addAll(tmpListA);
                return entries;
            }

            for (EntryA tmpEntryA : tmpListA)
            {
                if (tmpEntryA.filterMatch(filterValue.toLowerCase()))
                {
                    entries.add(tmpEntryA);
                }
            }
        }
        return entries;
    }
...
```

Comment: What happens if you remove `paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"`

Comment: Thanx, this works! This is great to know. But i shouldn't change this attribute